# Push extenal data with data from server to array

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am currently working on a project in which, I am fetching the data from server and adding(pushing) in the array for further process. And its working great.
I face problem when I add an external data to the array with the data coming from server.

```
var quantity= ItemsValue[1];
$scope.product = [];
$http.get(___).success(function(data) {
    $scope.greeting = data ;
    $scope.product.push($scope.greeting);
}
```

I want to push "quantity" with the "$scope.greeting". I already tried different thing such as concatenation but failed.

I want data of array to be like this. For Example

> $scope.product=[{ "greeting.name": "abc", "greeting.price": "50",
>   "quantity":"1" }]

Name and Price came from server and quantity in added as an extra data to Array.

```
<tbody >
<tr ng-repeat="greeting in product" ><!--  -->
            <td class="cart_product">
                <img src={{greeting.Image}} alt="book image" ></td>
            <td class="cart_description">
                <h4>{{greeting.Name}}</h4></td>
            <td class="cart_price">
                <p>Rs. {{greeting.Cost}}</p>
            </td>
            <td class="cart_quantity">
                                <div class="cart_quantity_button">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_up" href=""> + </a>
                                    <input class="cart_quantity_input" type="text" name="quantity" value="Itemsquantity" autocomplete="off" size="2">
                                    <a class="cart_quantity_down" href=""> - </a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_total">
                                <p class="cart_total_price">Rs. {{greeting.Cost}}</p>
                            </td>
                            <td class="cart_delete">
                                <a class="cart_quantity_delete" ng-click="removeItem($index)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
```

This is the code of client end.

Any way to push these things together...

Answer (score 1):

You can just add it into the object by creating a new property

```
var quantity = ItemsValue[1];
$scope.product = [];
$http.get(___).success(function(data) {
    $scope.greeting = data;
    $scope.greeting.quantity = quantity;
    $scope.product.push($scope.greeting);
}
```

Comment: I am using the greeting in view to display data

Comment: @ZiaUllahMinhas modified accordingly